# web_accessible_resources not working, requests result in "Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script that is creating an iframe inside of a page. Then it gets the url to an html page (`app.html`) bundled in the extension using `chrome.runtime.getURL('app.html')` and sets the `src` of the iframe to the result. This results in the iframe looking like this:

[image: extension resource load error]

This happens even though in my manifest I have:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"web_accessible_resources": ["*", "app.html"]
```

Additionally, I've disabled every other extension in my browser when testing and I still get this result. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I updated my Chrome from 78 to 79 and now it works. I have no idea why because `web_accessible_resources` has been a thing since somewhere in the 50s. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Without trying the actual extension myself I guess the path is wrong. Currently your code is written like app.html is in the root directory where manifest.json is.

Comment: `app.html` is actually in the same directory as `manifest.json`. I appreciate the response though!